# SQL - Errors caused by incorrect syntax near ',' and declaration of variables

Tags: sql, syntax-error, declaration

Please find below the code followed by the error messages. Desired output is YYYY_diff.

Code:

```
1  create function YYYY_diff 
2        (
3            @periods double, @yr1 double, @yr2 double, @dd1 double, @dd2 double
4        )
5
6     returns double
7     as
8     begin
9
10     declare @y1 double, @y2 double, @modYr double
11
12    set @yr1 = floor(@y1 / @modYr)
13
14    set @yr2 = floor(@y2 / @modYr)
15
16    set @dd1 = @y1 % @modYr
17
18    set @dd2 = @y2 % @modYr
19
20
21    select @periods,
22   
23     case when @modYr = 1 then 1 
24          when @modYr = 2 then 10
25          when @modYr = 4 then 10
26          when @modYr = 12 then 100
27       
28     end
29
30     set @YYYY_diff = (@yr2 - @yr1) * @periods + @dd2 - @dd1 + 1
31
32    return @YYYY_diff
33
34  end
```

Error messages:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@y1".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@y2".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@y1".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@y2".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@periods".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 30 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@yr2".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure YYYY_diff, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@YYYY_diff".

Comment: What's the database? Looks like Sybase or SQL Server but can't tell.

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain what database system you're using and *what this function is meant to do*, we could help you. As it is, you appear to have a function with 5 parameters that are all ignored/overwritten by logic that can't help but set most of them to null.

Comment: It’s SQL, sorry I tagged it thinking that would be enough but I’ll include it in the title next time

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql-server then double isn't a valid datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If Sql server,
try this: double is not a valid datatype,actually it is **double precision in sql**. Here for the below one, used **decimal** datatype. it wont throw any error.

```
  CREATE OR ALTER function YYYY_diff 
        (
           @periods DECIMAL, @yr1 DECIMAL, @yr2 DECIMAL, @dd1 DECIMAL, @dd2 DECIMAL
        )

    returns DECIMAL
     as
     begin

     declare @y1 DECIMAL, @y2 DECIMAL, @modYr DECIMAL

    set @yr1 = floor(@y1 / @modYr)

    set @yr2 = floor(@y2 / @modYr)

    set @dd1 = @y1 % @modYr

    set @dd2 = @y2 % @modYr


    select @periods=

     case when @modYr = 1 then 1 
          when @modYr = 2 then 10
          when @modYr = 4 then 10
          when @modYr = 12 then 100

     end
     DECLARE @YYYY_diff DECIMAL;
     set @YYYY_diff = CAST((@yr2 - @yr1) * @periods + @dd2 - @dd1 + 1  AS DECIMAL)

    return @YYYY_diff

  end
```

Comment: Also: mind you that `DECIMAL` without defining precision and scale defaults to `DECIMAL(18,0)` - thus **no digits** after the decimal point..... very often, this is neither desired, nor expected. You should always provide precision and scale to a `DECIMAL` type declaration to avoid any confusion

Comment: yes, knew it, Based on the requirement, would set precision and scale accordingly.